# rails best practice for a multistep form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rubygems

I want to create a mutlistep form in Rails 3. I've watched the railscasts episode on it, but I did not feel like he was using the best practice when creating the form. I felt like it was a sloppy way to accomplish the task. What is the best way to create a multistep form using the best practices in rails?

Comment: Can you give reasons as to why you think Ryan was 'sloppy' in doing his multistep forms?

Comment: i just felt like the controller had too much code inside the create action. is there no other way to create a multistep form?

Comment: ive seen in big sites like amazon and legalzoom, the whole checkout is done mostly as a GET request in the URL. is this a bad idea to do?

Comment: If you mean the form is retrieved as a GET and submitted as a POST/UPDATE, that's universal for HTTP-based forms.

Comment: Thomas - how are we doing for answering your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to answer without more information, and a true answer would be a detailed tutorial (like a Railscast) rather than a SO answer, but here's some thoughts to get you on your way.

There are two major approaches to multistep forms:

1. Use Javascript to display the form bit by bit
2. Create separate views and use `create`/`update` or similar to route the user from one to the next.

There are advantages to each method, depending on whether you want to support javascript, and what your requirements are about saving data in between sections.

Advantages of 1

- Faster for the user to navigate from section to section (javascript hide/show is instantaneous)
- Data is easily accessible is the user wants to refer to an earlier section
- Simpler controller actions

Disadvantages of 1

- Will not work for users who are not running javascript (and no progressive enhancement is really possible here other than displaying the form as a huge chunk).
- Will require you to provide javascript-based navigation to move from section to section (only a disadvantage if you're new to .js)
- Will require AJAX if you want to save the user's information between steps.
- Without AJAX and javascript, the user is at the risk of losing a lot of entry if the user accidentally pressing the back button, etc.

Comment: ive seen is some sites with multistep forms similar to what i want to do, they have it arranged like order/1 for step 1 and order/2 for step 2 and so on... the best way to accomplish this is to make a different controller method for each step right?

Comment: @Thomas - that's only *one* way as I've explained (that's method 2). Bear in mind many of the major sites probably use a sophisticated version of method 1.