# Rails How to create multiple step with list survey questionnaires

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, multi-step

I want to create a questionnaire page like [this link](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s.aspx?sm=3RTg/dHEWbKYEPJWeeqeeA==)

When user clicks Next, the page reload with new questions.If user presses Back, the page reload with questions that answered by this user. How can I implement this technical in Rails.

Comment: There are probably a dozen different ways to do this. Have you tried searching on Google? Some results to get you started http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605232/rails-best-practice-for-a-multistep-form

Comment: yep, I tried. But my question is not multiple step forms.

Comment: have you find any solution ??? i have the same problem